# Three circles each pair of which intersects at two points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

consider three circles in euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ each pair of which intersects at two points. Therefore any two circles determine one line (going through those two points where the circles meet), we get three lines altogether.

The claim is that those three lines meet at exactly ony point.

I tried to chose coordinates for all three circles and then did my best to determine the coordinates of the intersection point of the three lines. But it looks pretty complicated, it is a mess so to speak. Is there a more elegant approach to this problem?

Best wishes

Comment: Perhaps, "which *pairwise* intersect at two points" or better "each pair of which intersects at two points" is a less confusing way of putting the intersection criterion.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have changed my question accordingly. Is it now easier to understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is a special case of so called radical axis theorem, which states that for any three circles on a plane, three radical axes they define are concurrent.

If two circles intersect at two points, then their radical axis is a line through intersection points, which gives the result.